# Search in html Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xhtml

I have the below HTML code, also I will have a textbox for entering the keyword,
What I want is while the user writing in this textbox the javascript search in this HTML code using the FirstName and LastName, and while comparing items, if an item didn't match I want to `display: none` its container div.
How can I do that using JS and work on firefox and IE

```
<div id="contact_4">
    <input class="contactChk" id="chk_4" type="checkbox" />
    <img alt="" src='img/4.jpg' width="25px" height="25px" />
    <span id="contactName_4" class="contactItem">
        FirstName LastName
    </span>
    <br />
</div>
<div id="contact_5">
    <input class="contactChk" id="chk_5" type="checkbox" />
    <img alt="" src='img/5.jpg' width="25px" height="25px" />
    <span id="contactName_5" class="contactItem">
        ACharName AnyLast
    </span>
    <br />
</div>
<div id="contact_6">
    <input class="contactChk" id="chk_6" type="checkbox" />
    <img alt="" src='img/6.jpg' width="25px" height="25px" />
    <span id="contactName_6" class="contactItem">
        BCharName AnyLast
    </span>
    <br />
</div>
<div id="contact_7">
    <input class="contactChk" id="chk_7" type="checkbox" />
    <img alt="" src='img/7.jpg' width="25px" height="25px" />
    <span id="contactName_7" class="contactItem">
        CCharName AnyLast
    </span>
    <br />
</div>
```

Comment: I found this article, which really solved my problem and its faster than all other solutions i tried: [jQuery Inline Search Plugin](http://vision-media.ca/resources/jquery/jquery-inline-search-plugin)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks very inefficient if you have a larger set of contacts to be displayed. The easiest way would be to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and bind a function to keyup event of your text field: (assuming the above code is contained inside something like `<div id="contactlist">`)

```
var searchstring = "";

function filterContact() {
  var jthis = $(this); // should give a tiny performance gain
  if ($('span.contactItem', this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchstring) >= 0) {
    jthis.addClass('matching');
    jthis.removeClass('nonmatching');
  } else {
    jthis.addClass('nonmatching');
    jthis.removeClass('matching');
  }
}

function filterContacts() {
  var elem = $('input#yourtextfield')[0];
  searchstring = elem.value.toLowerCase(); // because we like to match all cases
  searchstring = searchstring.replace(/^\s+/,'').replace(/\s+$/,''); // trim

  $('#contactlist div').each(filterContact);
}

function initFiltering() {
  $('input#yourtextfield').live('keyup',filterContacts);
}

$(document).ready(initFiltering);
```

Also add `.matching` and `.nonmatching` classes to your CSS. (`display: block` and `none`)

As said, this is quite inefficient, not only by memory (and bandwidth) needed but also by CPU time on filtering (plus rendering time). It could be faster if you process that data inside some array or if you have very large datasets you should fetch the filtered data paginated from server on demand (can also be done by jQuery's AJAX functions). You could also filter delayed in case the user is still typing (filter only if he stopped typing for ~500ms).

`toLowerCase()` could have some difficulties with non-ASCII input; so if you need it you should test it on your target languages.

Comment: Check my answer it helped me more and worked perfect http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574816/search-in-html-javascript/903517#903517

Answer (score 1):

this may help you :

> **javascript**

```
<script language="javascript">
    function go() {
        elem = document.getElementById("thesearch");
        for (var x = 4; x <= 7; x++) {
            if (((document.getElementById('contactName_' + x).innerHTML).toUpperCase()).indexOf((elem.value).toUpperCase()) > -1)
                document.getElementById('contact_' + x).style.display = "";
            else
                document.getElementById('contact_' + x).style.display = "none";
        }

    }
</script>
```

> **HTML**

```
<input type="text" value="" id="thesearch" onkeyup="go();" />
```

Note the number of div to check is fixed and static in my example. This should be improved, but this example work in IE6 / FF3.

Hope this can help.

Edit: oh yeah, the toUpperCase() can be removed, if you want something case sensitive